# Automatically create Matplotlib Legend colors+labels from "c=..." argument

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data that looks like `X_1 = [...]`, `X_2 = [...]`, `Y = [...]`. The values in `Y` are integers representing labels and the values in `X_1` and `X_2` are floats. I want to make a scatterplot of `X_1` vs `X_2`, and have points coloured in using `Y`. I can do

```
plt.scatter(X_1, X_2, c=Y)
```

but I can't find any documentation describing how to get a legend that shows, for each label in `Y`, the corresponding colour used for the marker.

How can I create this legend?

Comment: do you mean for each label in _Y_?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

To have full control, you can make an empty scatterplot for every color, just to define the markers and labels that are going to appear in the legend:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_1 = [0.1, 0.5, 0.9]
X_2 = [0.3, 0.7, 0.2]
Y = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for color in Y:   
    ax.scatter([], [], c=color, label=color)

ax.scatter(X_1, X_2, c=Y)

ax.legend()
```

[image: scatterplot example]